# Google maps shows error info instead of map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I wanted to add a map with some custom markers on it to my project. On localhost everything works fine but when I've sent the code to the production server I got 'Sorry, we don't have map of this region in required scale' (or something similar). This is the code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var map;
    var mapStart = function(){
        if(GBrowserIsCompatible()){
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.961869,19.134521),6);
            map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
            var ikona1 = new GIcon();
            ikona1.image = "{{MEDIA_URL}}images/map_icon_1.png";
            ikona1.iconSize = new GSize(36, 30);
            ikona1.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(16,16);
            ikona1.iconAnchor = new GPoint(16,16);
            var data_map = {{ properties|safe }}       
            map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
            map.enableContinuousZoom();
            var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
            var maxlng =0;
            var maxlat=0;
            var minlng=0;
            var minlat=0;
            for (var i=0; i < data_map.length; i++){
                var pos_lat = parseFloat(data_map[i]['lat']);
                var pos_lon = parseFloat(data_map[i]['long']);
                addMarker(pos_lat, pos_lon,{icon:ikona1}, data_map[i]['info_box']
                );
                if (pos_lat < minlat || minlat==0){ minlat = pos_lat}
                if (pos_lat > maxlat || maxlat==0){ maxlat = pos_lat}
                if (pos_lon < minlng || minlng==0){minlng = pos_lon}
                    if (pos_lon > maxlng || maxlng==0){maxlng = pos_lon}
                lat = minlat + (( maxlat - minlat)/2);
                lng = minlng + (( maxlng - minlng)/2);
                var allpoints = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                bounds.extend(allpoints);
            }
            map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds)-2);
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        }
    }

    var addMarker = function(lat, lon, options, info_box_html){
        point = new GLatLng(lat,lon);
        var marker = new GMarker(point, options);

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(info_box_html);
        });

        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        mapStart();
    });   
    window.onunload = function (){ GUnload()};
</script>
```

and I have the following import (with new key generated):

`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=ABQIAAAA2YOYLBVnylQ7NK445E1_gxQFK8hZs27CqIA3jAe_qRgIGP9GQBTFZjebH-xe-6vEjhK0Pa9agV_Mpg"></script>`

data_map has proper form as I've already tested it locally. Also when I've commented out everything apart of creating map and adding control I got clear gray screen Anyone knows this error ?

Comment: Switch to Google Maps v3 if you can.

Comment: ok it looks that the lat/long parameters were broken on production server. Still when I've updated them, there's no map shown but grey screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have valid coordinates.  I wonder if you are sending map.setZoom a valid value.  What happens if don't set the zoom level?